# Transferring PayPal Recurring Subscription from Joomla to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, joomla, wpmu, aec

I am migrating a website with Joomla /AEC Subscription Manager (with PayPal Recurring Payments) to Wordpress with WPMU Membership plugin http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/membership/.

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to migrate the recurring paypal payments from AEC to Wordpress without having the users re-subscribe on Wordpress (and looking for some pointers on how this could be accomplished).

We can leave the joomla data intact, if it requires us to.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

This process can not be automated. You need to creates some plugin sort of for Joomla. This plugin will catch the response got from Paypal (URL can be found from AEC), process this data according to Wordpress subscriprion plugin and send this data to you our Wordpress site using CURL.

IMP: There is a subscription id, in the paypal notification data. You need to maintain a mapping between Joomla user and Wordpress user according to paypal subscription id.

It is little bit complex and totally depends upon the extension using in Wordpress site. You may also need to create a plugin Wordpress, which will catch the response from your previous Joomla site.